# HTMLAgilityPack - Get only the Head information without the body

Tags: c#, html, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to get a few meta tags from websites. The HTMLAgilityPack is excellent for that. My only issue is that it gets the entire website and filters through it. I was wondering if there was a way only to scrape the Head part without the body since I don't really need it in this case.

Here's what I have:

```
url = "some website"
var getHtmlDoc = new HtmlWeb();
var document = getHtmlDoc.Load(url); //document gets the entire website
var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
```

What I'm trying to do is find a way for the `getHtmlDoc.Load(url)` to leave the body when getting data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are asking is possible with `HtmlWeb`. With a proper HTTP client though (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) one), you can use the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) header on your request.

```
const string url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range";

var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, 5000);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The response might not contain the entire `<head>` element. Since picking the right range is just guessing, you will probably want to pick a high enough value and also implement a fallback.

```
const string url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range";
var rangeEnd = 5000;

// the request part
var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, rangeEnd);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// the fallback
while (html.IndexOf("</head>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <= 0)
{
    rangeEnd += 5000;
    request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, rangeEnd);

    response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

// the parsing
int indexOfClosingTag = html.IndexOf("</head>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

html = html.Substring(0, indexOfClosingTag + "</head>".Length);

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```